# Linear transformation's kernel and image of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

$T:\mathbb{R}[x]_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_3$ defines the linear transformation $$T(p(x))=p''(x)-xp'(x)+2p(x)$$
Write down the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]_3$ and explicitly describe the image and kernel of $T$.

First, I took the linear transformation of each element in the standard basis ($\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$) and got the matrix:
$$ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 6 & 0 & -1\end{array} \right]  $$

From this, how can I get the kernel and the image? I'm not even sure what is meant by these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the kernel you must find a basis for the space of vector $\vec{x}$ satisfying
$$A\vec{x}=\vec{0}.$$

The image is all $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}[x]_3$ such that $A\vec{x}=\vec{y}$. So we are trying to find a basis for the space $$A\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix}.$$  By matrix multiplication, this space is given by the linear combination of columns of $A$:
$$\vec{C}_1x_1+\vec{C}_2x_2+\vec{C}_3x_3+\vec{C}_4x_4,$$ where $C_n$ is the $n^{th}$ column of $A$.

Answer for Kernel:

> To find the Kernel, we perform row reduction on $A$ to solve the system $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ and find that the resulting matrix $A'$ is given by $$A'=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ Thus the kernel is given by $\text{Span} \{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}\}$

Answer for Column Space:

> Doing column operations is equivalent to doing row operations on $A^T$. To find the image, we row reduce $A^T$. Row reducing $A^T$ yields $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$ So the column space is given by $$\text{Span} \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} \} $$